# How to develop a settings page for an Android Auto app

Tags: android, android-auto

I currently develop a small app that displays some data from an API call on the car's display. For that an API is called on a regular basis and results get displayed in a GridTemplate. I now want the user to be able to set their own API key and also set how often the data should be updated. So I need to add a preference page, where a user is able to set the data and than it's needs to be stored permanently. Seems like there is no build in template, so how could I best do that?

Searched stackoverflow without success. Also asked chatGPT, which mentioned a SettingsTemplate that doesn't exist.
Thanks

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: I could do it completely manually, but I wonder if there is kind of build in capability or a best practice.